# parallel command won't ignore config files

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a bash script that uses bash command `parallel`

I find that when I run the script as a non root user, `parallel` still checks `/root/` directory for a config file named `.parallel`

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

parallel --semaphore --jobs=6 "echo hello"
parallel --semaphore --wait
```

Running the script as root works as expected. However running as non-root gives this error

```
chown bob:bob foo.sh
sudo -u bob -g bob ./foo.sh
parallel: Error: Cannot change into non-executable dir /root/.parallel: Permission denied
```

I've tried using the `--plain` flag to ignore configs

`parallel --semaphore --plain`

I've tried using a config pointed at /dev/null

`parallel --semaphore -C /dev/null`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/parallel-1.html

**How can I make parallel command not check for `/root/.parallel` config file?**

Comment: Perhaps try setting `PARALLEL_HOME` to a writeable dir (e.g. `export PARALLEL_HOME=$HOME`) then use the `--plain` option?

Comment: Try adding `-H` option for `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `$HOME` in `foo.sh` when running?

```
sudo -u bob -g bob ./foo.sh
```

If `$HOME` is not changed to `/home/bob` but instead remains `/root` then that will explain what you see.

You can add:

```
echo $HOME
```

to `foo.sh` to check.

Or (as @jared_mamrot says) set `$PARALLEL_HOME` explictly.

*Why does GNU Parallel need a writeable dir?*

`--semaphore` works by creating files in the dir.

Answer (score 0):

We must make sure that `$HOME` is a writable folder for the user that executes `parallel --semaphore` (or `sem` for short), e.g. thus:

```
export HOME=/tmp && parallel --semaphore <..>
```

Why? GNU Parallel needs $HOME to be a writeable dir, and tries to write to $HOME, which is by default a root-owned folder (`/`).

This is because `parallel --semaphore` needs to create temporary files in some location.